# Issues with scrolling through a popup with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Python and Selenium for web-scraping and automation. I'm trying to log in to Instagram, go to particular account, click their following, be able to scroll popup and follow people who are visible in the popup. This is my code:

```
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
import selenium as selenium
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
SIMILAR_ACCOUNT = "honeymoon"
USERNAME = "username"
PASSWORD = "password"

class InstaFollower:
    def __init__(self):
        
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
        self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")
    def login(self):
        self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")

         
        login_form = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginForm"]')))

         
        username = login_form.find_element(By.NAME, 'username')
        password = login_form.find_element(By.NAME, 'password')
        login_button = login_form.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]/button')

         
        username.send_keys(USERNAME)
        password.send_keys(PASSWORD)
        login_button.click()

         
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@aria-label="Instagram"]')))

    def find_followers(self):

        time.sleep(5)
         
        self.driver.get(f"https://www.instagram.com/{SIMILAR_ACCOUNT}/followers")

        time.sleep(5.2)
        
        modal_xpath = ('/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div')
        modal = self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=modal_xpath)
        for i in range(10):
             
             
            self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", modal)
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, modal_xpath)))


    def follow(self):
        all_buttons = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, value='/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/button/div/div')

        for button in all_buttons:
            try:
                button.click()
                time.sleep(1.1)
             
            except ElementClickInterceptedException:
                cancel_button = self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//button[contains(text(), 'Cancel')]")
                cancel_button.click()



bot = InstaFollower()
bot.login()
bot.find_followers()
bot.follow()
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\38161\PycharmProjects\ InstagramFollowerBot\main.py", line 78, in <module>
    bot.find_followers()
  File "C:\Users\38161\PycharmProjects\ InstagramFollowerBot\main.py", line 52, in find_followers
    modal = self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=modal_xpath)
  File "C:\Users\38161\PycharmProjects\ InstagramFollowerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 742, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "C:\Users\38161\PycharmProjects\ InstagramFollowerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 348, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\38161\PycharmProjects\ InstagramFollowerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div"}
  (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.111); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF657C32142+3514994]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF657850CE2]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6576F76AA]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF657741860]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65774197C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF657784EE7]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65776602F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6577828F6]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF657765D93]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF657734BDC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF657735C64]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF657C5E16B+3695259]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF657CB6737+4057191]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF657CAE4E3+4023827]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6579804F9+689705]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65785C048]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF657858044]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6578581C9]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6578488C4]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF896867344+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF896E626B1+33]
```

I tried with different Xpaths, but it still doesn't work. It logs in, goes to a particular account and clicks their following, but it doesn't follow visible accounts and it isn't scrolling through the popup.

Comment: I don't have time to find out what's really wrong here, but I can say that your xpath queries are not looking too good. Mostly it is possible to come up with shorter queries. So you might want to look into that as it makes stuff easier to work with and more stable.